# How does enemy HP scale in the Seamless Coop Mod? (1.5.1 and 2.0.0)

Tags: elden-ring

The extremely popular [Seamless Coop mod](https://www.nexusmods.com/eldenring/mods/510) changes the way enemy scaling works, but I can't find any description of exactly how.

- I've seen [some places](https://www.reddit.com/r/EldenRingMods/comments/10zf48y/seamless_coop_scaling_seems_way_off/jaagvq9/) claim *"1 person, 1x boss health. 2 people, 2x boss health. 3 people, 3.3x boss health."*  That post claims it's stated in one of the [mod's official posts](https://www.nexusmods.com/eldenring/mods/510?tab=articles), but I checked them all and didn't see it.
- [This official-looking Steam post](https://steamcommunity.com/app/1245620/discussions/0/3395163747104259416?l=dutch&ctp=80) says

  > Enemy scaling is fixed (it didn't work at all previously). It now mimics Elden Ring's (25%/50%/75%) buff on enemies for 1, 2, and 3 co-operators respectively.

  However, [the official changelog](https://www.nexusmods.com/eldenring/articles/275) doesn't mention that. Also the claim that *"enemy scaling didn't work at all previously"* is *definitely* false, as there is *extremely* noticeable scaling in 1.5.1.

So my question is, **what is the exact scaling formula for Seamless Coop 1.5.1** (the current latest stable build), and **did the formula change for v2.0.0**?